# Bookmarking several SalesForce.com account from multiple Organization IDs

Tags: salesforce

I have 6 logins to SalesForce.com to 6 different org ids.

Two of my logins, I have the orgId in the url. These two correctly links them to the Organization. The other 4 organizations I don't have a url for the Organization.  I tried copying the syntax and it doesn't seem to bring me to the correct organization.  For right now, I bookmarked the url from the email link when my account was set up.  Is there another way to correctly bookmark the different organizations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're using Chrome you might want to install this small plugin: https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/forcecom-logins/ldjbglicecgnpkpdhpbogkednmmbebec?hl=en.

It's pretty neat but in the end it uses the syntax from the end of Daniel's answer so if you're worried that somebody can see the generated link & plaintext password it might not be best for you.

Comment: eyescream,  I have downloaded that app.  but the problem is it missing a description or name so I know what app I am going into

Comment: You can put them into groups or fill in the description field so it'll show up when you hover over the username?

Comment: The groups helped.  Thanks Eyecream

Comment: Due to the amount of the accounts, I sometimes get the invalid login when go to another account.  I am not sure how SFDC handles their sessions but it does not seem to take in acount for different applications very well

Comment: You can be logged to multiple orgs in same browser just fine but the sessions will start to clash when the domains are the same. For example 2 sandboxes on cs7.salesforce.com will give you problems even if their names (username suffixes) are different. It's not really a SF limitation, the reason is how cookies are being matched to domains... You'll have same issue if you'd store passwords somewhere else like KeePass.

Answer (score 0):

The built in way to handle multiple Salesforce Org log ins is to use the [Environment Hub](http://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewHelpDoc?id=environment_hub_main.htm):

> The Environment Hub lets you view, connect, create, and log in to multiple Salesforce organizations from one location. This can be especially convenient if you use a large number of organizations for business, development, and testing.
>
> You must choose one organization as the Environment Hub (or hub organization), and can then connect all your other organizations (or member organizations) to the hub. You can establish single sign-on between the hub and member organizations, enabling users to seamlessly switch between them without having to provide login credentials.

There are a number of other options presented on the [Salesforce StackExchange site](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/598/how-do-you-manage-passwords-across-sfdc-orgs/607#607).
Incidentally, that is a great place to ask Salesforce specific questions as they will be more on topic there.

If you want to get more direct, you can just format the login link yourself:

```
https://www.salesforce.com/login.jsp?un=<url encoded username>&pw=<url encoded password>
```

If it is a sandbox swap the `www` out for `test`.